# How to connect Stripe terminal bluetooth reader to Android app using Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Is there anyone using Stripe Terminal Bluetooth readers. if Yes please help me for implementing this with Titanium app.
As I am new to Appcelerator Titanium i don't have idea so it will be great if i got steps

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has a custom SDK to do that: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-android

So you would need to create a module and implement that SDK. A documentation for the Stripe SDK is available at https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/connect-reader and a basic tutorial for Titanium Android module can be found at [from zero to app](https://fromzerotoapp.com/create-android-modules-for-titanium/) and in the [official documentation](https://titaniumsdk.com/guide/Titanium_SDK/Titanium_SDK_How-tos/Extending_Titanium_Mobile/Android_Module_Development_Guide/)